# C++ coins conversion hw

Tags: c++

The last part of my code doesn't seem to run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main() {

    int dollars;
    int cents;

    std::cout << "Please enter your amount in the format of dollars and cents separated by a space: ";
    std::cin >> dollars >> cents;

    double quarters = dollars/0.25;
    int whole_quarters = (int) quarters;

    double dimes = cents/10;
    int whole_dimes = (int) dimes;

    double nickels = (dimes - whole_dimes)/0.5;
    int whole_nickels = (int) nickels;

    int pennies = std::fmod((dimes - whole_dimes),0.5);

    std::cout << dollars << " dollars and " << cents << " cents are:\n";
    std::cout << whole_quarters << " quarter " << whole_dimes << " dimes " << whole_nickels << " nickels " << pennies << " pennies ";
    return 0;
}
```

I typed in 2 58 but the output was 8 quarters 5 dimes 0 nickels 0 pennies
It should be 1 nickels and 3 pennies
Can someone tell me what am i missing?

Comment: You mean '10 quarters'? Your output doesn't match the program you posted.

Comment: The output I get from the above program is `8 quarter 0 dimes 0 nickels 0 pennies` which is obviously wrong, but not the same output as you are claiming. Please confirm exactly what output you expect. But basically your formulas look to be incorrect, rather than this being anything subtle. But I don't want to fix the formulas until I know exactly output what you are expecting.

Comment: oh yea I just noticed the mistake. It's supposed to be 8 quarters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better answer would be 10 quarters, 1 nickle, 3 pennies. Be that as it may.

I wouldn't have used this particular algorithm, although scanning it isn't telling me the obvious problem. I would debug by dumping out dimes (the double) and verify it's what you think it is, and then nickles (the double) and make sure that value makes sense, too.

I would do something like this:

```
int dimes = cents / 10;
int nickles = (cents % 10) / 5;
int pennies = (cents % 5);
```

If cents is 58, then dimes = 5, cents % 10 is 8, divided by 5 is 1, and cents % 5 is 3.

But it's worthwhile, if you're serious about programming, to put a lot of cout statements into your code and make sure values are becoming what you think they are.

Also, this will be faster if instead of asking for input, you comment out that code and hardcode your test data. Once you're getting proper test results that way, then switch back to asking for input.